# How do generate jpeg from html and automatically post to facebook wall?

Tags: facebook, image

I have seen many facebook applications posting pictures to the walls of the users. How do they generate those pictures???

Answer (score 2):

Obviously using a graphics library.
For php you can use [GD](http://php.net/gd), [cairo](http://php.net/cairo). For complex UTF-8 text rendering you can use [pango](http://developer.gnome.org/pango/stable/). Its a library written in C.

Comment: Thanks. For the links. One more new library!

Comment: Thanks for the links. The server takes in user input and generates an html5 graph, I need to convert that graph into jpeg and post it to facebook wall. How do I achieve that?